# BitmapFrame.Create from non-writeable stream

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, stream, readonly

I created a class which inherits from Stream class and implemented most methods.
This stream class is read-only so I didn't implemented SetLength and Write methods. Generally it works great, but when I'm using the following line of code:

```
BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile, BitmapCacheOption.None);
```

**Sometimes** (about 40% of the time) it throws the same exception i throw in the SetLength method of my stream, meaning the BitmapFrame.Create method is trying to change the length of my stream.
How can I overcome this issue? I need the BitmapMetadata class. Why is the BitmapFrame.Create is even trying to edit my stream? is there any other way to get BitmapMetadata from read-only streams?

Comment: Just copy it into a MemoryStream beforehand...

Comment: @Nyerguds I'm handling 1000+ read-only streams in a very big length, copying each one to a memory stream will hurt the performance really bad.

Comment: So will the crashes. As it is, there is far too little information here for anyone to help you. Why are the streams readonly? How does that class look? Have you looked into the BitmapFrame msdn to see what may cause it to write? What is the stack trace of your exception? It might give insight into what part of the process is trying to set that length. None of these things are mentioned here.